# Probability of Card Dealing

Tags: probability

If you have a shuffled deck of 52 cards, and are dealing them out to 2 people would the individual probability of receiving a specific set of 2 cards be 1/2600 for the first person and 1/2499 for the second person or is my thinking incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is incorrect two ways.  There are ${52 \choose 2}=\frac {52 \cdot 51}2=1326$ pairs of cards.  If the first person draws two cards, the chance of any given pair is then $\frac 1{1326}$.  Assuming we don't look at those cards and then give two to the second person, the chance of any given pair for the second person is also $\frac 1{1326}$.  An alternate approach is to give two to the first player, two to the second, then tell them to swap cards.  If it was $\frac 1{1326}$ for the first originally, it is not $\frac 1{1326}$ for the second.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to deal exactly $2$ cards to each of the two people, without replacing the cards in the deck.

Then the answer is that the probability is $\frac{52\cdot 51}2$ for the first person, and exactly the same for the second.